# Mvc app is ignoring database constraints

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constraints

In my self proclaimed learning project I did stumble upon a weird error.

I have a class `device`

```
public class Device
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    /* .... */
}
```

and a class `Category`

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I try to delete a category directly in my database, the operation fails, because of the foreign key constraint still active - which is good and intended.

On my Mvc View however this constraint does not seem to be active. I can delete every category, no matter if it still in use within a device.

This results in devices without a category. When calling the Edit method in my controller, the viewmodel is filled with a selectlist, which contains every category and the devices category as a `selected`value.

```
var vm = new DeviceEditViewModel
{
    dev = device,
    CategoriesListItems = repo.GetCategories().Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.ID.ToString(),
        Text = x.Name,
        Selected = x.Name == dev.Category.Name
    }),
    ManufactorListItems = repo.GetManufactors().Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
         Value = x.ID.ToString(),
         Text = x.Name,
         Selected = x.Name == device.Manufactor.Name 
    })
};
return View(vm);
```

This piece of code now throws a NullReferenceException, when calling a device without a category.

How can I enforce a constraint check in my delete action for categories and how can I prevent the Dropdownlist in the edit view ton assign a selected value, if the data is inconsistent?

As for the constraint check, this is what I have tried so far, but does <del>not</del> work.

```
//I still have to create a repository
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
    int DevicesUsingCat = db.Devices.Include(o => o.Category)
                            .Where(d => d.Category.ID == id)
                            .Select(x => x).ToList().Count;
    if (DevicesUsingCat > 0)
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError("Usage", "The category is still in use and cannot be deleted.");
       return View(); //added. Now model error shows up.
    }
    db.Categories.Remove(category);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: What database are you using? Is it really the same db/schema where you connect directly and where you connect through your app?

Comment: I have 2 databases, with which I am testing. One is a local `.\SQLEXPRESS`, the other a full fledged SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: Are there really equal constraints in place in both of them?

Comment: `db.Categories.Remove(category);` Does remove the selected category from the table.

Comment: Does it also remove child records?

Comment: There are no child records. Category is only linked to device. So if I delete a category there are 1- n devices with a categoryId of `null`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39820/discussion-between-jva-and-serv)